# How to map kubelet port to POD

Tags: kubernetes

One of my kubernetes Node, I see my kubelet listening on port 38641. How to map this port number to actual POD its pointing too.

```
# netstat -alpn |grep 38641
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38641         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9832/kubelet
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45230         127.0.0.1:38641         CLOSE_WAIT  9832/kubelet
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:39922         127.0.0.1:38641         CLOSE_WAIT  9832/kubelet
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:39238         127.0.0.1:38641         ESTABLISHED 9832/kubelet
```

Comment: can you please attach the results of this commands:
`sudo netstat -alpn |grep kube-proxy
kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o wide`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have exposed a service in kubernetes using the NodePort type which would account for the high port number. If this is the case, you can simply get a list of all services running in the cluster and search then for the port you want. ie.

`kubectl get svc --all-namespaces | grep 38641`

Once you have the service which exposes this port, you can then inspect the service and see which pods are being selected by the service

```
PORT=38641
SERVICE_OUTPUT=$(kubectl get svc --all-namespaces | grep $PORT)
NAMESPACE=$(echo $SERVICE_OUTPUT | awk '{ print $1 }')
SERVICE=$(echo $SERVICE_OUTPUT | awk '{ print $2 }')
kubectl describe -n $NAMESPACE svc $SERVICE
```

Now let's get the selector:

```
SELECTOR=$(kubectl describe -n $NAMESPACE svc $SERVICE | grep Selector | awk '{ print $2}')
```

Ok, now that we know what pods are being selected we can find these pods easily:

`kubectl get po --selector $SELECTOR -n $NAMESPACE`

We can capture the pod names for further inspection, such as for determining the replicaset they are from:

```
PODS=$(kubectl get po --selector $SELECTOR -n $NAMESPACE --no-headers=true | awk '{ print $1}')
echo $PODS
```

If you need to you can trace the pod origin:

```
POD=full-pod-name
RS=$(kubectl -n $NAMESPACE describe po $POD | grep -hoe ReplicaSet.*); 
echo rs: $RS;

DEPLOYMENT=$(kubectl -n $NAMESPACE describe $RS | grep -hoe Deployment.*); 
echo deployment: $DEPLOYMENT;
```

Comment: I tried this didn't see this port in my service list. that's why posted message here.

Comment: you ran with --all-namespaces?

Comment: yes, I ran these two command `kg svc --all-namespaces -o yaml |grep 38641` and `kg all --all-namespaces -o yaml |grep 38641` not returning any output

Comment: what is kg? I'm not familiar with this command. Maybe try running the raw command instead of using an alias or third party function. Also you should check to see that your kubectl is configured to talk to the correct cluster via the commands `kubectl cluster-info` and `kubectl config get-contexts`

Comment: `kg` is alias for `kubectl get`. I am running the command on correct cluster.

Comment: does your cluster have rbac enabled? maybe the use you are using doesnt have permission to see certain resources.

Comment: yes, 1.11 cluster RBAC enabled. I am using admin account to query the cluster.